# I am trying to move my laravel project to production and i can't resolve this error GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException cURL error 7

Tags: laravel, api, digital-ocean, guzzle, centos8

I am trying to move my laravel project to Production and i can't get rid of this error:

> ```
> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException
> cURL error 7: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
> ```

I am using PHP 7.2.24 using LAMP stack in CentOS 8 environment. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Silly question but did you go to the URL and look at error 7? CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7) Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

Comment: Please check `curl` install in your server?? In your server `curl` not install that's why you get this error

Comment: This could be a multitude of things, such as having port 80,443 closed from outgoin on your prod server from the ip not being white listed.

Comment: provide the complete error, it doesn't specify much eg something like this 
    GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to www.abcwebsite.com port 80: Connection timed out

Comment: That's all i'm getting with no other details. :(

Comment: "A GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException exception is thrown in the event of a networking error." as per Guzzle docs, you can handle this exception in a catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running the following command:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect true
```

and restarting apache solved the issue.